# Need to calculate hours difference between two dates

Tags: apex, trigger, formula-field

I have requirement where i need to calculate the time differnece between two datetime fields called Sent__c and Verify__c in hours with in business hours to 8am to 4.30pmGMT+2(those two dates are populating with in the business hours). i have tried like this but its not working at all 
can anyone help me please.

```
      (Sent__c - Verify__c ) * 24(this is the formula which i have tried and not working)

Eg:  Verify Date -  2020/03/17 4:30 PM
Sent date - 2020/03/23 3:10 PM
03/17(Tuesday time) – 0 Hours
03/18(Wednesday time) – 8 Hours
03/19(Thursday time) – 8 hours
03/20(Friday time) – 8 hours
03/21(Saturday) – 0 hours
03/22(Sunday) – 0 hours
03/23 (Monday time)– 7 hours 10 min
**Excepted**
Total Hours is – 31 Hours 10 min
```

Comment: Please check this link: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ZglhAAC

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, 16 place do i need to enter 4.30 like 1900-01-08 04:30:00, but i am not understanding , how to add GMT+2 here

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the relevant info (formula) instead of using comments as they're hard to read.